# pdf processing don with no error but the pdf cannot open manually itextSharp c#

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have a template pdf (1 page) that I need to

- copy to another and editing (put images on it)
- duplicate the page depending on image list count
- the template should be background while the image over content

-> the debugging mode run successfully but the new pdf file cant open, error msg image:
[image]

here the source code:

```
//start editing the pdf 
        using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream(filepathsrc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (Stream outputPdfStream = new FileStream(filepathOut, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            //read the template
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepathsrc);
            //copy the template the original
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);

            //set template under content
            PdfImportedPage Page = stamper.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
            PdfContentByte background = stamper.GetUnderContent(1);
            background.AddTemplate(Page, 0, 0);

            //create pages
            int originalpages = imageBytes.Count;
            for (int page = 1; page <= originalpages; page++)
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = reader.GetCropBox(1);
                stamper.InsertPage(page , rect);
            }
            //duplicate template for page one
            for (int page = 2; page <= originalpages; page++)
            {
                stamper.ReplacePage(reader, page - 1, page);
            }

            //place images
            for (int i = 0; i < imageBytes.Count; i++)
            {
                int pageNum = i + 1;
                PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(pageNum);
                pdfContentByte.AddImage(images[i]);
                
            }

           
        }
```

I'm junior developer I will be thankful for explanation the issue on my code.

Comment: You forgot to close the `PdfStamper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like what @mkl said, I forget to close `pdfstamper` .